# How to send raw data via POST to a WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make POST to an external webapi sending "raw" data. I could successfully do it using for example Postman, but when I tried to do it in my MVC App, I get the following error: *Specified value does not have a ':' separator. Parameter name: header*.

This is my code for calling the webapi:

```
public UserCustom GetUserByToken(string pToken)
{
    ResponseLogin vRespuesta = new ResponseLogin();
    UserCarmocal vUsuarioFinal = null;

    string vApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"];
    string vDirUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointUsr"];
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(vDirUser);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Headers.Add("ApiKey", vApiKey);

    string postData = pToken;

    //I THINK THE ERROR IS IN THE NEXT LINE:
    request.Headers.Add(postData);

    using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            vRespuesta = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseLogin>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            if (vRespuesta.status == "success")
            { vUsuarioFinal.FirstName = "Test"; }
        }
    }

    return vUsuarioFinal;
}
```

Comment: " I get an error", unfortunately, we are not magicians. You need to [edit] your question and include the exact error being thrown

Comment: Tks Camilo, I added the error description.

Comment: `Headers.Add` is for adding headers, not the content of your request. Headers are in the format of something like `Auth Token: Bearer Something`

Comment: I will edit my question with the new result from webnoob suggestion.

Comment: are you passing pToken value in `Body => raw` in postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the pToken variable to request stream

PSUEDO CODE

```
    public UserCustom GetUserByToken(string pToken)
    {
        ResponseLogin vRespuesta = new ResponseLogin();
        UserCarmocal vUsuarioFinal = null;

        string vApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"];
        string vDirUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointUsr"];
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(vDirUser);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers.Add("ApiKey", vApiKey);

        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pToken);

        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        stream.Flush();

        using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                vRespuesta = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseLogin>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                if (vRespuesta.status == "success")
                { vUsuarioFinal.FirstName = "Test"; }
            }
        }

        return vUsuarioFinal;
    }
```